# My interceptors are not fetching values from action page to FTL in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, freemarker

I am not able to find the issue that why my FTL couldn't fetch values from action page.

**This is my FTL code:**

```xml
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<#assign temp = 12311>
<h4>hello world  : ${FirstAction?if_exists.random} #{temp}</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my `struts.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
        value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
  <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
  
    <action name="getTutorial" class="MyActions.FirstAction" >
      <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
      <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="submit" class="MyActions.FirstAction" method="submit"></action>
    
    <action name="callme" class="MyActions.FirstAction" method="myMethod">
      <result name="success">/FreeMarkerPages/testingAction.jsp</result>
      <result name="failure"  type="freemarker">/FreeMarkerPages/FirstFTL.ftl</result>
    </action>
    
  </package>
</struts>
```

**This is my action class:**

```java
package MyActions;

import java.util.Random;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import service.ColorPicker;

    public class FirstAction extends ActionSupport{
        private int random;
        public String execute() {
            return "failure";
        }
        public String myMethod(){
            setRandom(9999);
            System.out.println("My method "+random);    
            return "failure";
        }
        
        public String submit(){
            System.out.println(random);
            return null;
        }
        
        public int getRandom() {
            return random;
        }
        public void setRandom(int random) {
            this.random = random;
        }
```

**This is my FTL error :**

```xml
FreeMarker template error (HTML_DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!)
```

> The following has evaluated to null or missing:
> ==> FirstAction?if_exists.random  [in template "FreeMarkerPages/FirstFTL.ftl" at line 5, column 22]

Comment: What is `FirstAction` is your ftl?

Comment: FitstAction is a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake. Instead of writing `${FirstAction?if_exists.random}` i should have written `${random?if_exists}`.

This is not a static class.

Answer (score 0):

You have used deprecated api. See [Handling missing values](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing).

> Note:
>
> These operators exist since FreeMarker 2.3.7 (replacing the `default`,
>   `exists` and `if_exists` built-ins).

---

If you want to lean how properties are resolved in Struts 2 you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32868476/573032) answer.