# Struts2 : FreeMarker template error: UBUNTU OS, but

Tags: struts2

When we run below code in windows its running fine. But in UBUNTU, its throwing below exception

Code:

```
<s:textfield  name="realname" id="realname" placeholder="User Name" class="form-control" > </s:textfield>
```

FreeMarker template error:

> The following has evaluated to null or missing:
>
> ==> ww  [in template "template/simple/text.ftl" at line 10, column 11]
>
> Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??

FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):

> - Failed at: @ww.property value="parameters.nameVa...  [in template "template/simple/text.ftl" at line 10, column 9]

Java stack trace:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:134)
    at freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException.newDescriptionBuilder(UnexpectedTypeException.java:85)
```

Comment: <s:textfield  name="realname" id="realname" placeholder="User Name" class="form-control" > </s:textfield>..   When I am removing name attribute then its working fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43161362/573032